# Why \chemand produces [0pt]+ in mychemistry?

Tags: chemistry

I was writing chemical reaction using `mychemistry` package. I have a problem with `\chemand` which produces [0pt]+ as output in pdflatex. How can I get rid of the [0pt]?

```
\begin{rxn}
\reactant{\chemname{\chemfig{*6(------)}}{Cyclohexane}} 
\arrow[,,1.50]{\scriptsize Pt on}{\scriptsize \ch{Al2O3xH2O}}
\reactant{\chemname{\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Benzene}}
\chemand
\reactant{3\ch{H2}}
\end{rxn}
```

[image]

Comment: The `mychemistry` package is classified as obsolete by its author. The wrong output is due to an internally called `\chemsign` macro that's not defined any longer.

Comment: As commented above the package is obsolete and should not be used. If you do want to use it, then for this specific issue you can add `\newcommand{\chemsign}[2][]{#2}` below `\usepackage{mychemistry}` which will output a (somewhat misaligned) `+` sign for the MWE.

Comment: Thank you very much. I usually use mhchem package to write simple chemical reactions and did not know that mychemistry package is obsolete ! I think I better use chemfig as Mr. Clemens suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The `mychemistry` package is obsolete and not updated any longer (the last update was nearly 5 years ago). It used to have its purposes before v1.0 of `chemfig` was published on 2011/06/15. Since v1.0 `chemfig` comes with a built-in mechanism for reaction schemes.

`mychemistry` used to build upon `chemfig` which means it also uses commands provided by `chemfig`. `chemfig` used to have a command called `\chemsign` until v1.2 (2015/10/08). `chemfig` itself removed this command in favor of its more advanced scheme mechanism.

The scheme from the OP without `mychemistry`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{*6(------)}}{Cyclohexane}
    \arrow{->[\scriptsize Pt on][\scriptsize \ch{Al2O3xH2O}]}[,2]
    \chemname{\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Benzene}
    \+
    \ch{3 H2}
  \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you Sir !! I didn't know that the package became obsolete. Thanks for your explanation and correction. It works now !